# Unable to get output for multiplication

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
  int n[50],p=0;
  double g=1;
  char c;
  cout<<"\n press a for addition";
  cout<<"\n press m for multiplication";
  cin>>c;
  if(c=='a')
  {
    for(int i=0;n[i]=!'=',i<50;i++)
    {
      cin>>n[i];
      p+=n[i];
    }
    cout<<p;
  }
  else if(c=='m')
  {
    for(int j=0;n[j]=!'=',j<50;j++)
    {
      cin>>n[j];
      g*=n[j];
    }
    cout<<g;
  }
  else cout<<"wrong input";
}
```

I have wrote this code, it works perfectly fine when addition part is used but when multiplication is done it isn't giving the final product. Whenever I click '=' it doesn't give any final product during multiplication but while addition the same logic works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple problems:

- The array `n` isn't initialized so its contents will be *indeterminate*, and using indeterminate values lead to *undefined behavior*.
- Fortunately (for you) the loop "condition" expression `n[j]=!'=',j<50` doesn't do what you probably think it does... The part `n[j]=!'='` is actually equal to `n[j] = !'='`. That is you assign the result of `!'='` to `n[j]`.
- And about the loop "condition", the result of `n[j]=!'=',j<50` is the result of `j<50` *only*, because that's how the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) works.
- With `cin>>n[j]` you can't read arbitrary characters, as `n[j]` is an `int` and you only read `int` values. The only way to get a `'='` from the input is if the user inputs the value `61` which happens to be the ASCII encoded value for `'='`.
- Your loop "condition" also have another flaw, because you increase `j` before you check `n[j]`, so in the condition `n[j]` will always be an element of the array that you haven't read into.
- And building on the previous point, because the value of `j` will be wrong in the "condition" you will go out of bounds of the array which also leads to *undefined behavior*.